# PDFBox omits form fields when page is cloned

Tags: pdf, groovy, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I'm trying to create a multi-page document using PDFBox and Groovy. 
I have a template document which contains some form text fields and everytime a new document should be created, the program uses this template.

My problem is that whenever I try to create a new document, some form fields in the new doc are missing. I work with Foxit PhantomPDF and, Visually, I can't see the missing fields. The other ones which I do see are fine.

Here is my code:

```
static void initiatePdf() {
        // Initiate a new PDF Box object and get the acro form from it
        File file = new File(Constants.EMPTY_DOC)
        PDDocument tempDoc

        Evaluator evaluator = new Evaluator()
        int numPages = evaluator.getNumOfPagesRequired(objects)

        for(int i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
            tempDoc = new PDDocument().load(file)

            PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = tempDoc.getDocumentCatalog()
            PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.acroForm

            PDPage page = (PDPage) docCatalog.getPages().get(0)

            document.addPage(page)
        }

        document.save(Constants.RESULT_FILE)
        document.close()
    }
```

Here are an images that will help depict my problem. This is the template:

[image]

This is the new pdf file

[image]

Comment: You're not setting the fields of your destination Acroform in any way. Your destination PDF does not have an Acroform entry. You have not adjusted the destination pages of your Annotation widgets to their pages. You have not explained whether all fields at the same position but on different pages should be "connected". Also,  (unrelated) change `new PDDocument().load(file)` to `PDDocument.load(file)` (static method).

Comment: It would also be helpful to share source and destination PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this problem with the help of Tilman Hausherr. Here is the code located after the for loop.

```
PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(document, acroFormDict);
acroForm.setFields(fields)
acroForm.setDefaultResources(res);

PDDocumentCatalog catalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
catalog.setAcroForm(acroForm);
```